# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, readfile

I am trying to create a program that will read from a file on my computer.
The file consists of simply door numbers from 1-150 within a bracket.

The error returns at line 6. `print(file.read())`

```
#opening_a_file.py

file = "This PC/C:/Python Programming/Doors.txt","r"

print("read function: ")
print(file.read())
print()

file.seek(0)
```

I tried renaming the file absolute path.
I edited line 3 as well to read as:

```
file = open("This PC/c:/Python Programming/Doors.txt","r")
```

but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the variable `file` is a tuple. That is what happens when you define it in tuple format: `var = value1, value2`

So, in your case, you want a file object, so you need to do this:

```
file = open("C:/Python Programming/Doors.txt","r")
```

For the sake of the answer, here is the full code sum-up:

```
file = open("C:/Python Programming/Doors.txt","r")

print("read function: ")
print(file.read())
print()

file.seek(0)
```

Comment: Yes, I also did try that. But, when I use that code, it returns an error:

[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'This PC/C:/Python Programming/Doors.txt'
  File "C:\Users\Nick\#opening_a_file.py", line 3, in <module>
    file = open("This PC/C:/Python Programming/Doors.txt","r")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'This PC/C:/Python Programming/Doors.txt'

Comment: @abraki94 Then that is not a valid file path.

Comment: Okay, what does a valid file path look like?

Comment: @abraki94 You want to remove the `This PC/`. Also, are you sure the file is located in that exact location

Comment: I renamed the file to Python_Programming and removed the "This PC/" and it worked!
Thank you!